# yii2:Call to undefined method Closure::allows() in denyCallback

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

i use Yii2 framework
this is my behaviors function in `ShippingController`

```
  public function behaviors()
        {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    // deny all POST requests
//                        [
//                        'actions' => ['index', 'create'],
//                        'allow' => TRUE,
//                    ],
                        [
                        'actions' => ['index', 'create', 'init'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                        'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action)
                            {
                            return $action->controller->redirect('action');
                            }
                    ],
                    'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action)
                        {
                        return $action->controller->redirect('not');
                        }
                // everything else is denied
                ],
            ],
        ];

        }
```

matchCallback  is worked good but

in`denyCallback` i have this error :

Error
    Call to undefined method Closure::allows()

what is my problem ???!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

move `denyCallback` element outside of the rules array
it needs to be on the same level with `class` and `rules`